# remove top margin between uiview and uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiview

There is a weird line of spacing between the top `UIView` and `UITableview`. Does anyone know how to fix it? Unchecking adjust scroll view inset is not working for me.

[image]

Comment: May be you need to set header height 0 or `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: Is this a grouped or plain table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the previous answer. You need to remove the `headerView` from your tableView and call `layoutIfNeeded()` to apply the change and remove the blank space:

```
yourtableView.tableHeaderView?.removeFromSuperview()
yourtableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
yourtableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `tableViewHeader` with an empty `UIView()`

Try this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

or try this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: try now with the updated answer